# iOS InApp Purchase

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I just wonder if there is anyway to check if a user(email) already buy an in app purchase item in my application.

For example I buy an item on my iPhone, then I log in on my iPad with same itune account. the application will know that this user did buy the item.

Thanks,
Huy

Comment: Your back-end can just keep track?

Comment: What type of in-app purchase? Consumable?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening when you use the restore purchased option in many applications.

```
SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored
```

is the constant retrieved from server when you tries to purchase an already purchased item.

Please check this nice tutorial about inApp purchase : [inApp purchases](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2797/introduction-to-in-app-purchases)

Answer (score 0):

From the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1):

> Store Kit provides built-in functionality to restore transactions for
>   non-consumable products, auto-renewable subscriptions and free
>   subscriptions.

You can restore purchases with the `StoreKit` framework by calling the `restoreCompletedTransactions` method of the `SKPaymentQueue`. Your app will then receive a transaction for each product the user has previously purchased. Simply handle these transaction and unlock the features and/or download content on the new device.

If your product is a consumable (gold coins for your game, health packs etc.) this would **not** apply and you have to keep track of the purchases on your own.

You will need to set up a server that will keep track of each transaction. And you need to implement a method to authenticate the user across devices (signup via e-mail, Facebook login etc.). Once the user logs in on a new device, your server can tell the app what it should unlock/download.